# How to make a specific folder of my application appear in gallery?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, storage

I have this code that stores correctly in the internal storage of my mobile in the folder of the application creating a folder called "credentials", how can I register that folder in the Gallery?

```
private void ObtenerCaptura() {
            try {
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").Format(new Java.Util.Date());
                string folder = GetExternalFilesDir("credenciales").ToString();
                string folderFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, timeStamp + ".jpg");
                var fos = new FileStream(folderFile, FileMode.CreateNew);
                bitmapCorte.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, fos);
                fos.Close();
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Captura guardada.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.SetTitle("Funciones Android");
                alert.SetMessage("Ha ocurrido un error al cargar la captura.");
                alert.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (senders, args) =>
                {
                    //
                });
                Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
                dialog.Window.SetType(WindowManagerTypes.SystemAlert);
                dialog.Show();
                Log.Info(typeof(PolylineTask).Name, "Error al crear FileStream en ObtenerCaptura");
                Log.Error(typeof(PolylineTask).Name, e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a new app to test this question and the following method is worked:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage(this.ContentResolver, myBitmap, "SocialPhoto", "testing");
```

Note:

1.you need to get the Bitmap format of the picture;

2.you need to add permission in AndroidManifest file, and add Runtime Permisssion in Android M and above.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Effectively, complying with the requirements of the Manifesto, as I mentioned, saving does not cause problems, just how to make a folder of a place in a place where it is in gallery, try that line of code, just as I'm trying with 3 different APIS, Thanks!

Comment: I really do not work, I do not even appear in Gallery, and I put the code bitmap that I show in my question

Comment: @AdolfoCelis  Do you mean when you insert image into gallery, it don't show in gallery?  I have tested on two android mobiles, it does works.